# This code runs with no errors but cannot get it to copy the data needed

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-apps-script, scripting

I am trying to copy data from one sheet to another. I understand some java script but since this throws no errors i cannot figure out why it isn't working correctly. I know how to make it copy from one sheet to another if the sheets stay the same however this pulls from a new sheet everyday so i am not able to pull from a named sheet. I have this script attached to a button that activates the script. The button works good but won't pull the data.

```
function Copy() {

   var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

   var firstRow  = ss.getRange("C101");


if(firstRow.getValue()  > 0 ) {


   var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
   var s  = ss.getActiveSheet();
   var range = s.getRange("A101:I101");
   var data = range.getValue();

   var tss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
   var ts = tss.getSheetByName("report");
   ts.getRange(ts.getLastRow()+1).setValue(data);
}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about following script?
In order to get data from A101 to I101, you can use "getValues()". In the case of "getValue", data of only "A101" is got. And in order to copy data from A101 to I101 to other spreadsheet, you can use "setValues()". By this, you can copy data from A101 to I101 to other spreadsheet.

About how to use spreadsheet on Google Drive, you can see this document. https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#open(File)

```
function Copy(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var as = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var data = as.getRange("a101:i106").getValues();
  var ar = [];
  for (i in data){
if (parseInt(data[i][2]) > 0) {
  ar.push(data[i]);
}
}
  var ts = ss.getSheetByName("report");
  ts.getRange(ts.getLastRow()+1, 1, ar.length, ar[0].length).setValues(ar);
}
```

Comment: It runs without any errors but still won't copy data to the "Report" sheet for some reason.

Comment: As a sample to test, I made 2 spreadsheets. One is included this script. Another is only sheet. I put "-1" from A101 to I101 to first one. And it runs this script. At this sample, data from A101 to I101 can be copied to other spreadsheet. What are "some reasons"?

Comment: The File name is "Daily Vital Ratios 2017" and "report" is one of the only sheets inside the file that doesn't have the name change daily. I have a new sheet created everyday that is named the date that it is created on. I want to pull data from each new sheet created and put it on a report sheet to make it easy to move to a reporting file that shows data trends.

Comment: Do you want to copy from a certain sheet in spreadsheet with name of "Daily Vital Ratios 2017" to a sheet with name of "report" in spreadsheet with name of "Daily Vital Ratios 2017"?

Comment: I have a button named " data push " that i click on at the end of everyday and i want copied from the new sheet created that day over to the " Report " sheet. All the sheets are located in the " Daily Vital Ratios 2017" file.

Comment: I have a button call " Submit" that hides the sheet created that day and copies the original sheet, names it to the new day and copies all the buttons over to the new sheet.

Comment: I updated the script now. The script can copy from active sheet on "Daily Vital Ratios 2017" to "report" sheet on "Daily Vital Ratios 2017".

Comment: Was your problem be solved? If it's not, let me know. I'll think for solving.

Comment: It still won't move data to the "Report" sheet. This is where i have been stumped all day. It seem like a simple enough script but it won't copy the data over.

Comment: Can I see the spreadsheet? Or your sample spreadsheet which I can see?

Comment: Thank you. From now, I have to work for about 30 minutes. After this, I will update the script. I apologize for my problem.

Comment: After i asked for help with the script i scrolled to the bottom of the report sheet and found that one of the things i had tried worked but i couldn't duplicate it as i am still learning how the scripts work.

Comment: I sent a request for accessing, just now.

Comment: Can I see the script? I don't run and modify.

Comment: you should be able to access the script as you have editing privileges.

Comment: Thank you. I'll see the script.

Comment: Just one more thing the code runs good but the new sheets overwrite the previously copied data. How would i make it go to the next line instead of overwriting the data?